# Creating sub domain on webmin

Tags: subdomain, ubuntu, webmin

Can anybody help me in creating subdoain through webmin. I want to create subdomain like test.xxxxx.com for this I tried with several reference site but no luck.
exp.

http://www.trickylinux.net/add-domain-virtualminwebmin.html

http://codeboxlabs.com/add-subdomain-webmin-linux/

My current httpd.conf look like:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
SSLEngine off 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/******/web
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "/var/www/html/*****/web">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName www.******/.com
ServerAlias ftp.*****.com
SSLEngine off 
SSLVerifyClient optional
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Also some more can be found using our search using tags > http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subdomain+apache+virtualhost

Comment: Can you send me the question link.

Comment: Also no proper solution is available for both questions.

Comment: There is many other questions on setting up Apache with an virtual host, regardless if you are using webmin, directadmin or cpanel they all use Apache and use the same virtual file as you linked. Please use the search, we don't allow questions catered to just you when questions already exist regardless of the answers left (people can leave answers on exiting questions at any time and creating another one to gain attention is not allowed). Again, I recommend you to use the search, there are many questions and answers already on typical setup of the virtual host file.